# error No lock file in this directory. Run yarn install to generate one. LERNA JENKINS

Tags: node.js, jenkins, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I am using Lerna (https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for managing my monorepo with the following structure:

```
-yarn.lock
-package.json
-node_modules
-packages
--app
---app1
----package.json
----src
----dist
```

(The above structure is the minimal example I could give, actual project has many more sub repos but this is the only one that's built on Jenkins.)

On my local machine with Yarn and NPM version as follows:

```
yarn: 1.22.10
node: v12.14.1
```

I run the following commands to build my **APP1** from my root directory

```
yarn
cd ./packages/app/app1
yarn build
```

which generates dist folder in packages/app/app1.

But when I run the same set of commands on Jenkins I get the following error:

```
error No lockfile in this directory. Run yarn install to generate one.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Since I'm using lerna, my lockfile is in root directory. Why am I getting this error? Why not on local machine?

Node and Yarn versions on Jenkins:

```
yarn: 1.9.10
node: v12.16.1
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the tips run "yarn install",then run "yarn upgrade"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32812599)